# Global access to elements with same class name using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, upload

I searched all forums for the answer and i couldnt find one...
Well look the problem is simple. :)

I adding classes with same CLASS name "FileSelect" ( They are input type=file) and i want to calculate before uploading all file sizes.

I can do it for each one class and determine the size will sent.
Onchange function i do this:

```
$(function(){   
    $('.FileSelect').live('change', function() {

        var totalSize=0;
        for ( var i=0 ; i< this.files.length ; i++)
        {
            totalSize += this.files[i].size ;
        }
        alert(totalSize);   
    });
});
```

=======================================================================
Now the problem is that i have a delete button in each file and i want to subtrct the size
each time on delete. But the problem is that when u click "delete" button u dont have access to "this" variable because it is outside the FileSelect.

So the simple solution at this point is to access ALL classes with name FileSelect and
ask for size. I do this but not workin.

`$(".FileSelect").files.length ;`

So how can u change "this" variable so u can have global access to elements with same className ..... ?

Comment: Where do you have this delete button? How do you choose to delete which '.FileSelect'?

Answer (score 3):

`files` is a property of DOM element and not jQuery use this.

```
$(".FileSelect")[0].files.length
```

Without looking at your markup it is difficult to say whether `this` can be used to access the `input:file` fields.

Comment: Well thank you so much, you are the man ! Solution was simple after all and with your help.. So i let other know... If you have inputs (files) under the same class Name, this is what you do in jQuery to determine file size will be sent: Let us have class Name like "FileSelect" : 

`for ( var i=0 ; i< $(".FileSelect").size() ; i++ )

{

       for ( var j=0 ; j< $(".FileSelect")[i].files.length  ; j++ )

       {

   alert ( $(".FileSelect")[i].files[j].size) ;
       }
  
}`


I alert each one size but you can add the bytes size in one variable. 
I love this forum... ! xD